# Can I trigger a function when a audio object begins to play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have an `<audio>` object that might need to load before it can play, is there a way to trigger a function when either the sound begins after downloading, or when the user clicks the play button?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is `onplay` event for audio and video, you should use `<audio>` tag to do it

```
var audio = document.getElementById("Your_audio");
audio.onplay = function() {
  //your code
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `playing` event you can listen to like so.

```
audio.addEventListener("playing", function() {
    console.log("playing");
});
```

http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#eventdef-media-playing

Answer (score 0):

with the javascript audio object you can add some event listener, like  :

```
var horn = new Audio('car_horn.wav');
horn.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  let duration = horn.duration;
  // The duration variable now holds the duration (in seconds) of the audio clip 
})
```

as you can see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add an evenListner like this:

```
<audio|video onplay="myScript">
```

e.g. you can do like this:

```
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.onplay = function() {
    alert("The audio has started to play");
};
```